# rails_admin search through nested belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a model:

```
class TenantReference < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TenantReferenceAdmin
  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :reference
  default_scope { eager_load(:tenant) }
end
```

and a Tenant model:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { eager_load(:user) }
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tenants, :foreign_key => :user_id, class_name: 'Tenant'
end
```

and finally a TenantReferenceAdmin rails admin file:

```
module TenantReferenceAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      list do
        field :tenant do
          filterable true
          queryable true
          searchable [ :first_name, :last_name]
        end
    ...
```

what I'm trying to achieve is that in the tenantreference admin page the user can search TenantReference objects by the first_name or last_name of the user through their Tenant reference.

This configuration is producing a postgresql query like:

```
SELECT  "tenant_references"."id" AS t0_r0, .... "tenants"."id" AS t1_r0, ......
FROM "tenant_references" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tenants" ON "tenants"."id" = "tenant_references"."tenant_id" 
WHERE ((tenants.first_name ILIKE '%query%') 
  OR (tenants.last_name ILIKE '%query%') 
ORDER BY tenant_references.id desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0)
```

which doesn't work, because first/last_name are actually fields of user, not of tenant.

how could I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you not need something like `searchable: [{User => :first_name, :last_name}]`? I don't know RailsAdmin and can't see anything in the docs about the `searchable` option, though!

Comment: thanks, I tried but I couldn't get any way to have the join include the User model, I expect there to be an extra join like: `JOIN users ON users.id = tenants.user_id` but because tenant_references has no straight `belongs_to :user, through: :tenant` I don't see a way to make this happen. The problem is having the JOIN there, with that there's no problem having the WHERE sorted

Comment: Could you not therefore add a `has_many through` from User to TenantReferences through Tenant? Then Rails will know about this direct relation you want to use.

Comment: thanks, indeed adding the has_one through made it work fine, describing the solution in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that rails admin only adds `JOIN` to the query if the current model has a direct link (`has_many`, `has_one` ...) to the other model to search in. and it joins it if the corresponding field is marked as `queryable true`.

so I changed adding to the references model this line:

`has_one :user, through: :tenant`

I then created an invisible list field:

```
    field :user do
      visible false
      queryable true
      searchable [{User => :first_name}, {User => :last_name}]
    end
```

that can be searched upon, but it's not shown in the list.

this has solved the issue, I don't consider this ideal as I had to modify my model in order to be able to perform rails_admin search, when rails_admin could have handled this situation without changing the code. But for now I can live with this